# Listing Non-Record

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.

1st table:

called kimlik

```
  id        ad
 ---------------
 1         ahmet
 2         mehmet
 3         ali
```

2nd table:

called siparis

```
 id        kimlikid     tarih                      miktar
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 1         1              22.09.2011           10 
 1         2              22.09.2011           100
```

I want to list via SQL query to persons who doesn't give an order on 22.09.2011.

Result:

```
 ad             tarih    
 --------------------------
 ali           22.09.2011
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some methods:

### NOT IN

```
DECLARE @NoDateWanted date = '22.09.2011';

SELECT ad, @NoDateWanted as tarih
FROM
    kimlik k
WHERE
    k.ID NOT IN (SELECT kimlikid FROM siparis s WHERE s.tarih = @NoDateWanted)
```

### NOT EXISTS

```
DECLARE @NoDateWanted date = '22.09.2011';

SELECT ad, @NoDateWanted as tarih
FROM
    kimlik k
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'kimlik' FROM siparis s 
               WHERE k.id = s.kimlikid 
                     and s.tarih = @NoDateWanted)
```

### LEFT JOIN

```
DECLARE @NoDateWanted date = '22.09.2011';

SELECT ad, @NoDateWanted as tarih
FROM
    kimlik k
    left join siparis s 
         on s.kimlikid = k.id
         and s.tarih = @NoDateWanted
WHERE s.id IS NULL
```

The method you choose is usually down to personal preference and performance (they can produce different query plans depending on your data volumes), ie: **NOT EXISTS** is frequently faster than **LEFT JOIN** if siparis has 1,000s of rows per kimlik id.

EDIT: Added on variable to compare and display in result set

Comment: +1 FYI NOT EXISTS is safest because of NULLs and NOT IN. And quicker because it is a semi-join rather then join with filter. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/the-use-of-not-logic-in-relation-to-indexes/4010#4010

Comment: +1 good answer (although none of the 3 give the result in the Q)

Answer (score 5):

The 4th way is to use `EXCEPT` (aka `MINUS`) where the RDBMS supports it.
This should give the same execution plan as `NOT EXISTS`

```
DECLARE @NoDateWanted date = '20110922';

SELECT id, @NoDateWanted AS tarih
FROM kimlik
EXCEPT
SELECT id, @NoDateWanted 
FROM siparis
WHERE tarih = @NoDateWanted;
```

You'll have to add the date filter in as a constant.
When you check for "no rows" there is no row to pull the data from of course.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT k.ad, s.tarih
FROM kimlik k
JOIN siparis s on k.kimlikid = s.id
WHERE k.id NOT IN (
         SELECT si.kimlikid 
         FROM si.siparis
         WHERE si.tarih = '22.09.2011')
```

Comment: -1 in general this would return too many rows and will give the 'wrong' `tarih` - it should always be '22.09.2011' according to the sample result