# Why does NOT IN with a set containing NULL always return FALSE/NULL?

Tags: postgresql, query, null, informix

I had a query (for Postgres and Informix) with a `NOT IN` clause containing a subquery that in some cases returned `NULL` values, causing that clause (and the entire query) to fail to return anything.

What's the best way to understand this? I thought of `NULL` as something without a value, and therefore wasn't expecting the query to fail, but obviously that's not the correct way to think of `NULL`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Boolean logic - or [Three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)

- IN is shorthand for a series of OR conditions
- `x NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)` is the same as `NOT (x = 1 OR x = 2 OR x = NULL)`
- ... is the same as `x <> 1 AND x <> 2 AND x <> NULL`
- ... is the same as `true AND true AND unknown` **
- ... = `unknown` **
- ... which is almost the same as `false` in this case as it will not pass the `WHERE` condition **

Now, this is why folk use `EXISTS` + `NOT EXISTS` rather than `IN` + `NOT IN`. Also see [The use of NOT logic in relation to indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/the-use-of-not-logic-in-relation-to-indexes/4010#4010) for more

** Note: `unknown` is the same as `false` at the end of an expression in a `WHERE` condition.
While the expression is being evaluated, then it is unknown
See @kgrittn's comment below for why

Comment: Even with the clarification it is technically wrong, and in a way that could burn someone.  For example, if you view `x <> NULL` as resolving to `FALSE`, you would expect `NOT (x <> NULL)` to evaluate to `TRUE`, and it doesn't.  *Both* evaluate to `UNKNOWN`.  The trick is that a row is selected only if the `WHERE` clause (if present) evaluates to `TRUE` -- a row is omitted if the clause evaluates to either `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`.  This behavior (in general, and for the `NOT IN` predicate in particular) is mandated by the SQL standard.

Comment: Also `NULL NOT IN (some_subquery)` should not return the outer row except if `some_subquery` doesn't return any rows. Which is why the execution plan when both columns are Null-able can be considerably more expensive. [SQL Server Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/73226)