# Best way to work around NOT IN NULL issue?

Tags: stored-procedures, null, sybase, except

There are plenty of explanations of why NOT IN NULL doesn't work, but I didn't see any solutions. (recent question here: [Why does NOT IN with a set containing NULL always return FALSE/NULL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17407/why-does-not-in-with-a-set-containing-null-always-return-false-null))

I have 6 optional arguments to a stored procedure that are used to filter a certain value of a query. The previous developer did something like this:

```
IF @var1 IS NULL AND ..... 

    select ...

else

    select ...
    where value in (@var1, ...)
```

I didn't particularly like this. (The query is quite massive), so I decided to opt for something like this: 
(We had the results in a temp table anyway)

```
IF @var IS NOT NULL OR ...

    delete from #temp where value not in (@var1,...)
```

But I realized that this won't work.

The only thing I can think to do is to create another temp table that will hold only the not-null values in @var1, etc. (Either using if statements or deleting where is NULL) and then doing a join delete on this table.

Is there a better way?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I think it's `NOT IN` that hes worried about.  With `NOT IN` you get no results from your query

Comment: @JNK. hehe well.. that is a different matter.

Comment: Is it an option to give these variables default values?  If  you give them a value you know will never be present, say an empty string, or -123456 or something, it should be fine to not change any other code.  I hate using magic numbers, though.

Comment: I thought about that @JNK, but that just seems silly..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know about Sybase but in SQL Server you can do like this.

```
select *
from yourtable
where value not in (select N
                    from (values (@var1),
                                 (@var2),
                                 (@var3),
                                 (@var4),
                                 (@var5)) T(N)
                    where N is not null)
```

If you can't use `values` to create a derived table you can use `union all` instead.

```
where value not in (select N
                    from (select @var1 union all
                          select @var2 union all
                          select @var3 union all
                          select @var4 union all
                          select @var5) T(N)
                    where N is not null)
```

Comment: Is there any performance repercussion to doing so many sub-queries? Or will the server be smart enough to realize it doesn't need to be evaluated for each row of `yourtable`

Comment: In SQL Server it gets treated as a derived table, so it only gets calculated once.  The only time you get a row-by-row execution is if the outer table value is used in the inner table, normally.

Answer (score 3):

This should work the same.

```
select ...
from
    yourtable T1
    JOIN
    (
      SELECT value FROM yourtable§
      EXCEPT SELECT @var1
      EXCEPT SELECT @var2
      EXCEPT SELECT @var3
      EXCEPT SELECT @var4
      EXCEPT SELECT @var5
      EXCEPT SELECT @var6
    ) T2 ON T1.value = T2.value 
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've already come up with by yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE #values (value varchar(8) NOT NULL)

IF @val1 IS NOT NULL INSERT #VALUES (value) SELECT @val1
IF @val2 IS NOT NULL INSERT #VALUES (value) SELECT @val2
IF @val3 IS NOT NULL INSERT #VALUES (value) SELECT @val3
IF @val4 IS NOT NULL INSERT #VALUES (value) SELECT @val4
IF @val5 IS NOT NULL INSERT #VALUES (value) SELECT @val5
IF @val6 IS NOT NULL INSERT #VALUES (value) SELECT @val6    

SELECT *
FROM table tab
WHERE value IN (SELECT value FROM #values)
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM table tab
WHERE value IN (ISNULL(@val1,'')
               ,ISNULL(@val2,'')
               ,ISNULL(@val3,'')
               ,ISNULL(@val4,'')
               ,ISNULL(@val5,'')
               ,ISNULL(@val6,''))
```

Adjust the `ISNULL(@val,'whatever_really_not_exists')`.

To understand `NULLs` better I recommend reading the Sybase documentation about

```
set ansinull [ on | off ]
```

or a [nice article by Robert Vollman](http://sybasease.blogspot.com/2005/05/nulls-in-sybase-ase.html) about `NULLs`.